# Given a string, return a string where every character in the original is doubled

Tags: c#, strings

For example, given the string "xyz", return the string "xxyyzz".

I was given this as a part of a test. I would really appreciate if you can help me to find a better way of doing it.

I came up with two methods to do the same thing but one was an extension method.

I have a couple more questions which I will post in separate posts.

```
public class RepeatCharactersInString
{               
    public string RepeatAString(string sInputString, int repeatCount)
    {

        StringBuilder sOutputString = new StringBuilder();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sInputString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty string !");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in sInputString)
            {
                sOutputString.Append(new String(c, repeatCount));
            }
        }

        return sOutputString.ToString();
    }

}

// Method 2 Using extension methods
public static class RepeatCharactersInStingExtensions
{

    public static string RepeatAllCharactersInThisString(this string sInputString, int repeatCount)
    {
        StringBuilder sOutputString = new StringBuilder();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sInputString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Empty string !");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (char c in sInputString)
            {
                sOutputString.Append(new String(c, repeatCount));
            }
        }

        return sOutputString.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class RepeatCharactersInString
public static class RepeatCharactersInStingExtensions
```

Those are weird class names. I don't think this method warrants its own class, so I would call the classes something like `StringUtils` and `StringExtensions`.

---

```
public string RepeatAString(string sInputString, int repeatCount)
```

- This method should be `static`. If a method doesn't use any instance members and it doesn't have to be an instance method for another reason, it's usually best to make it `static`.
- `RepeatAString` is a weir name for a method. I would call it `Repeat` or `RepeatCharacters`.
- Don't use [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for variables. You already specified the variable type once, there is no need to repeat it in its name. The right name for the first parameter would be `inputString`.
- The choice to have `repeatCount` is an interesting one. On one hand, the problem statement doesn't ask for it, so you're making your code more complicated unnecessarily (this is called [You Aren't Gonna Need It or YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)). On the other hand, it's an extension that makes sense and doesn't require much code. In the end, I think it was a good choice.

---

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sInputString))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Empty string !");
}
```

A library method like this one usually shouldn't write to the console. If you consider empty input invalid, throw an exception. If you consider it valid, just return an empty string.

---

```
sOutputString.Append(new String(c, repeatCount));
```

The premature optimizer in me says that you shouldn't allocate strings like this, it's inefficient. And since there is [an overload of `Append` that does exactly what you want without allocating a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e), you should use that.

Also, `string` is usually spelled in lowercase, just like you used elsewhere in the method.

Answer (score 3):

No reason to write anything when string is empty.

```
public string RepeatAString(string sInputString, int repeatCount)
{
    StringBuilder sOutputString = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (char c in sInputString)
        sOutputString.Append(new String(c, repeatCount));

    return sOutputString.ToString();
}
```

I think your solution is the best. Obviously you can use LINQ if you want but IMO it doesn't bring anything to table.

```
public string RepeatAString(string input, int count)
{
    return String.Concat(input.Select(c => new String(c, count)));

}
```

Comment: You mean, LINQ doesn't bring anything except for shortening the code significantly?